# Triangles/lines in transparent objects in OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

When I draw a plane with a transparent texture (for example the windows of a house), I see lines or triangles where they are not supposed to be. How can I fix this?

[image: triangles]
<sub>(source: [troll.ws](http://i.troll.ws/c9821713.png))</sub>

Here is the method I use to draw one window. I temporary enable blending to make the window transparent.

```
 static void drawWindow(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    Textures.window.bind();
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(startX, startY, 0);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2d(1, 1);
    glVertex3d(0, 0, 0);
    glTexCoord2d(0, 1);
    glVertex3d(endX - startX, endY - startY, 0);
    glTexCoord2d(0, 0);
    glVertex3d(endX - startX, endY - startY, 200);
    glTexCoord2d(1, 0);
    glVertex3d(0, 0, 200);
    glEnd();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);

    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Comment: Why are you using immediate mode? Using IM has been discouraged ever since vertex arrays got available, so for almost 20 years. _Why_ for all what is good on earth are you *hardcoding* your geometry? Put your geometry in a file that you load at runtime and render it using vertex arrays.

Comment: Have you got polygon smoothing turned on?

Comment: @JasonD Thanks for your comment. Yes it is turned on. When I disable it, the lines are indeed gone. Should I just turn it off then?

Comment: yes, it's not serving any useful purpose and is causing you problems. Use some more modern form of anti-aliasing (MSAA, etc.) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by having polygon smoothing turned on, which causes GL to render the edges of the polygons differently, causing issues with alpha-blending.

It's an outdated form of AA, so best to turn it off, and use a full scene anti-aliasing method instead, such as MSAA or other similar technique.

And standard advice also applies - the fixed function pipeline is antiquated and deprecated, and generally just not recommended.